# How to avoid path django.urls.path() funtion interpreting ? in url?

Tags: django, url, http-request-parameters

I want to set an optional request parameter in my view. But ? interprets to %3F.

I have tried the following code:

```py
app_name = "account"
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('profile/<int:user_id>/', UserProfileManager.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
    path('profile/<int:user_id>/?edit=<str:edit>', UserProfileManager.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
    ...
]
```

```html
<a href="{% url 'account:user_profile' member.id 'true' %}"> Edit your profile </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it in your url.  Change your template to

```
<a href="{% url 'account:user_profile' member.id %}?edit=True"> Edit your profile </a>
```